# page numbers are too far in GridView

Tags: asp.net, css

i am trying to change the distance between the pager numbers appearing in my GridView. i am using a css file in order to control the style of the grid.

[image]

```
.gridViewPager td a
{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
text-align:justify right;
}

.gridViewPager td a:hover
{
color: white;
text-decoration: underline;
text-align:justify right;
}
.gridViewPager span
{
text-autospace:none;
color: black;
text-align:justify right;
}
```

Comment: i would have add a screenshot but due to the site restrictions i am not allowed to add.

Comment: thanks for editing the question, i couldn't get it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to everyone
the problem was that each number was on a separate cell in a table which is located in the gridview pager footer, so by changing the column size I was able to get them closer together.

```
.gridViewPager td
{
    padding: 1px;
    width:5%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to .gridViewPager td a:

```
display: block;
padding: 2px 5px;
```

That will give you 2px on top and bottom, and 5px on either side of the a element.

Comment: thanks
but the thing won't budge. maybe I am using too much unnecessary definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Just call CssClass="gridViewPager " inside the Grid. The class definition is as follows,

```
         .gridViewPager  tr.paging td {
               background-color: #FFFFFF;
                   border-bottom: 0;
                   color: #000000;
                   font-size:13px;
               padding:0 4px 0 0;
                 } 
         .gridViewPager  tr.paging {
              background-color: #FFFFFF;
                  border: 0;
                  color: #000000;
                  font-size: 12px;
                  padding:0;
                 } 
        .gridViewPager  tr.paging td span {
                 color:#993366;
             text-decoration:underline; 
                 font-size:13px;
                 } 
        .gridViewPager  tr.paging td a {
             color:#000000;
             text-decoration:none;
                }
        .gridViewPager  tr.paging td a:hover {
             color:#993366;
             text-decoration:underline;
               }
```

Check the result first and then adjust the padding and other styles as you like.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem when you use table and there is no fixed width set on the table columns.
So your columns will occupy all available space.

May be you can set a max-width on the td and the table and set padding:0 7px; on td as well.

This would limit the space available to the cells.